# Can I find which object/variable in a webpage's javascript stack holds a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome Developer Tools (if someone knows a solution for another web dev environment, that would also be acceptable), can I find which variable holds a specific value?

The value is unique, and the page is generating http gets based on this value. It's non-random, and not contained in the page source as an element attribute or anything like that. The webapp already has jquery loaded up, and I suspect that the answer is a matter of iterating through some collection of objects or another at the console.

Can this be done?

Comment: You can just type the variable name in the console to get the value

Comment: @adeneo I do not know what it is. I already know the value, I'm trying to determine the variable name.

Comment: Oh, going the other way would be immensly difficult, at least if you have no idea of scope either. If it's global, you could probably do a `for` loop and check the values etc.

Comment: @adeneo Doubt very much that it's global, and the js is minified. I'd like to include an extra link in each page, and I can inject html/js to do that, but I can't construct a valid link unless I can figure out which variable actually has the magic value... doesn't seem to be any other way to derive it.

Comment: I have no idea how you'd do that, you'd probably have to start at `window` and then just iterate recursively out from there until you find the value.

Comment: If this variable is hidden in a IIFE, there is a good chance that there will be no way to access it.  Is this value hardcoded in the script? Or loaded via AJAX? Can't you extract it from other 'valid' links?

Comment: @KonradDzwinel The value changes, per page. I can extract it myself by watching the network tab... but that means I can't write a js snippet to make use of it. Not hardcoded in the script for certain.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that website? It's quite hard to speculate how it is built.